# Minimal Web API and seeding an in-memory Entity Framework database

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I successfully created a minimal C# ASP.NET Core 6.0 Web API project in Visual Studio 2022 using [Microsoft's minimal Web API tutorial located here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/min-web-api).

In this tutorial, the author uses an in-memory Entity Framework database. I would like to seed the database with fake data when the program starts.

I'm not sure where or how I can access my `DbContext` to seed initial data in the database. The author states, "The DI container provides access to the database context and other services." This is correct, but I would like to access the `DbContext` outside the scope of the Map methods (`app.MapGet`, `app.MapPost`, etc.)

How can I do something like this when the application starts?

```
db.ToDoEntities.AddRange(new List<ToDoEntity>
{
    new ToDoEntity
    {
        Name = "Code",
        IsComplete = false
    },
    new ToDoEntity
    {
        Name = "Game",
        IsComplete = false
    },
    new ToDoEntity
    {
        Name = "Sleep",
        IsComplete = false
    }
});

db.SaveChanges();
```

Here is the code I have so far:

```
// ToDoDbContext.cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace ToDo.Api;

public class ToDoDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ToDoDbContext(DbContextOptions<ToDoDbContext> options) : base(options) { }
    public DbSet<ToDoEntity> ToDoEntities => Set<ToDoEntity>();
}

// ToDoEntity.cs
namespace ToDo.Api;

public class ToDoEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = "";
    public bool IsComplete { get; set; }
}

// Program.cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using ToDo.Api;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ToDoDbContext>(options => options.UseInMemoryDatabase("ToDoList"));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

var app = builder.Build();

// Example GET end-point.
app.MapGet("/to-do-items", async (ToDoDbContext db) => await db.ToDoEntities.ToListAsync());

// All other map operations here. See the tutorial for the full code.

app.Run();
```

Answer (score -1):

Go to ToDoDbContext and add this method

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    //Example
    modelBuilder.Entity<ToDoEntity>().HasData(
    new ToDoEntity{ id= 1, Name = "First", Code = false },
    new ToDoEntity{ id= 2, Name = "First", Code = false ​});
}
```

then run add-migration through your vs studio terminal
which will generate a migration based on your data seed
then
run update-database

reference Visit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding

Comment: I added the OnModelCreating method but needed to change the type DbModelBuilder to type ModelBuilder. I added the Microsoft.Asp.NetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore NuGet package as a reference. I ran the command "Add-Migration SeedToDoTable" in the Package Manager Console. I received this error

System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.IMigrator'.

Comment: Install Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations, tools, look up which ef nuget packages that must be installed in your application for the migration to run

Comment: I think this path I'm following is incorrect. The docs on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/in-memory/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli state that "The in-memory database is designed for testing only". I might be better off using an actual database where migrations are allowed or using regular Web APIs. The author of the Minimal Web API instructions probably chose to use an in-memory database since it's simple enough to illustrate his point.